# Remove alert dialog border in custom Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

In my application i am using custom dialog .my dialog have rounded rectangle border and i can not remove that.please help me to set style for that to remove border. Thanks

```
public class myDialog extends Dialog
    {
        private String mMessage = "";

        public myDialog(Context context, String message)
        {
            super(context);
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
            mMessage = message;
            setCancelable(false);
            setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            setContentView(v);
            getWindow().setLayout(300,150);
            getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.);
        }
    }
```

My dialog cutom Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@drawable/dialog"
              >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been a long time frustrating issue with dialogs in Android. The only way I've been able to solve it, is by extending `DialogFragment` instead of `Dialog` and adding the following:

*YourDialog.java*

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.ActivityDialog);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

*styles.xml*

```
<style name="ActivityDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/ActivityDialog</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

android:border = "invisible"
or transparent. You can find the info online